# Should I index a property used in a NSSortDescriptor?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

If I am executing a Core Data fetch request, and applying a sort descriptor such as say:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort= [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"createDate" ascending:NO];
```

should the property `createDate` be an indexed property? Why or why not?

Comment: It's part of the Core Data SQLite datastore. In the object model, each property has the option to be indexed.

Comment: I think I have never used an indexed property. Have you tried it with and without?

Comment: Well it works either way, but I think it might have an impact on performance. I just want to know whether there are any guidelines relating to this practice..

Answer (score 0):

[According to the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002875-SW3), yes, if you have a sql backed store.  The predicate and sort descriptors are compiled and evaluated in the database where you will get an indexing advantage.

See the "Fetch Predicate and Sort Descriptors" section.

Answer (score 0):

Database indexes come with a price. The database will have to keep the index up to date, which slows down inserts, deletes and possibly updates. Write performance.

But indexes speed up queries and order by clauses. Read performance.

It's a tradeoff between the two. What's most important for you? Read or write performance?

Well, indexes have another side effect: memory usage. If you need to sort some entries even only once, without an index, you'll have to sort them in memory. Which means loading them in memory, all of them. At least the columns you are sorting, not the whole thing. But still.

As always, instrumentation is the best way to decide what is best.